# What can I do if my French financial institution refuses to complete their part of French Form 5000 and 5002?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, france, tax-treaty

My French financial institution (Sogecap) refuses to complete their part of [French Form 5000](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5000EN-2.pdf) ([mirror 1](https://archive.vn/1qClF),  [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805233357/https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5000EN-2.pdf)) a.k.a. CERFA 5000 and  [French Form 5002](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5002EN-2.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181118082931/https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/5002EN-2.pdf)) a.k.a. CERFA 5002. This prevents me from submitting Forms 5000 and 5002 to the Fisc (= French tax authority). I suspect they're simply too lazy to fill Form 5002 (or lost some records to do so).

What are my possible recourses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great information from [d4m1en](https://www.reddit.com/user/d4m1en) on https://redd.it/k104iy:

> **Step 1: write to customer service**
> SOGECAP
> Service Relations Clients
> 42, boulevard Alexandre Martin
> 45057 Orléans Cedex 1
> Phone 09 69 362 362
>
> **Step 2: write to customer complaints**
> Sogécap Réclamations Clients
> 42, boulevard Alexandre Martin
> 45057 Orléans Cedex 1
>
> **Step 3: write to ombudsman**
> La Médiation de l’Assurance TSA 50110 75 441 Paris Cedex 09
> http://www.mediation-assurance.org/Saisir+le+mediateur
> Ombudsman will ask for evidence of the two previous steps and at least 2 months without satisfactory answer, before taking your case.

The same 3-step process is described on https://www.assurances.societegenerale.com/fr/reclamation/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/V0ZLk#collapse2203-1)). Note that all French financial institutions are required to display the recourse processes somewhere on their website.

In parallel, one can message the Fisc via one's account on  https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/ to inform them of the issue.