# Is there any way to "certify the content" when mailing documents from France to a financial institution also located in France?

Tags: legal, france, mailing

I'm having some issues with a French financial institution, which claims they are some missing pages in some forms I sent them via [registered mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_mail). While registered mail certifies the reception, it doesn't certify the content, which isn't much useful if the recipient can simply say the content of the mail is empty or partially missing.

Is there any way to "certify the content" when mailing documents from France to a financial institution also located in France, so that the financial institution cannot pretend that some documents are missing?

Comment: That would be what an *huissier* is for. What are you trying to achieve, though? At some point you might also stop engaging with them directly and demanding whatever it is you are entitled to through the courts.

Comment: @Relaxed thank you, I'm reading that notaire is instead the best option (see answer below). I agree that at some point one has to seek other resources: [What can I do if my French financial institution refuses to complete their part of French Form 5000 and 5002?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133184/5656). (in my case the missing page is the verso of a sheet from which they acknowledged the reception of the recto! but they keep saying that some of the services in their financial institution have access to my original sheet, so in the end nobody on their end seems able to find the verso…)

Comment: What may have happened is that all documents are scanned upon arrival. With a US health care company, I have had the versa/reverse side of a sheet not scanned which caused a refusal of the reimbursement request. I only send them single-sided sheets now. AKA their scanning employees/contractor is not good. The original documents are destroyed so there's no hope of them 'finding' the missing page.

Comment: @mkennedy correct, documents are scanned upon reception. However in this case I'm quite sure they have kept the original, for archival purpose and because from my understanding they need to send the original documents to the tax authorities.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic due to being about how the the postal service works, not personal finance.

Comment: @RonJohn That goes beyond the postal service, as the answer shows.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your question is all and only about certifying the contents of a post.  "It belongs here because I'm mailing it to a financial institution" is diengenuous.

Comment: @RonJohn Certifying the contents of a mail is mostly useful when money is at stake, e.g. when the recipient is some financial  institution, tax authorities, etc.

Comment: No matter how you slice it, questions about how the Post Office works does not fall into any on-topic category: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @RonJohn that'd fall under Taxes in my case, as I need to certify the content to be able to move forward for some tax process.

Comment: Nope.  This is about the post office, not taxes.

Comment: @RonJohn a typical notary doesn't work at a post office.

Comment: Stubborn assertions don't work, since the question could easily be about one medium-sized business mailing a contract to another medium-sized business.

Comment: @RonJohn & Franck Dernoncourt Ultimately the question really is about forcing a financial institution to recognize a claim of some sort, which seems on-topic. The solution might or might not involve the post office (going through an *huissier* doesn't, they would deliver the document in person). Maybe the question could be edited to make that clearer, that's more-or-less what my initial comment hinted at.

Comment: Incidentally, the post office does offer a [related service](https://www.laposte.fr/lettre-recommandee-en-ligne/verifier-preuve) but I wouldn't consider that an answer if it's not clear that it would be enough to address the underlying issue.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks, I agree this seems like a great option. The main downside is that I don't think we can use this process in the case where original documents have to be sent (i.e., when scans aren't accepted by the recipient, which happens to be my case). Regarding the huissier, could we simply hire a huissier and ask them to certify+deliver the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting answer from [clupean](https://www.reddit.com/user/clupean) on https://redd.it/k2fn0b:

> This is common, you simply need to go to a **notaire** and ask for a **preuve de contenu**. Give him your documents and a prepaid envelope with the address and he'll write a single page listing the contents and saying that they checked everything. The notary will keep a photocopy of everything and they will seal and send the letter themselves.
>
> The envelope should also contain an attestation addressed to the institution receiving it with a list of everything and a short text saying that the contents have been certified with the contact info of the notary.

Another good idea from [CatherinefromFrance](https://www.reddit.com/user/CatherinefromFrance) on https://redd.it/k2fn0b (but this isn't possible to use this option in the case where original documents have to be sent, i.e. when scans aren't accepted by the recipient):

> In fact online by the french post LA POSTE you can send LRAR (Lettre Recommandée avec Accusé de Réception /registered letter with acknowledgment of receipt)
>
> - https://www.laposte.fr/lettre-recommandee-en-ligne
> - https://www.laposte.fr/lettre-recommandee-en-ligne/verifier-preuve
>
> "In the event of a dispute or doubt about sending a registered letter, this service allows you to check:
>
> The validity of your electronic proof with the information it contains, that the registered letter in your possession corresponds to the one sent."
>
> " La vérification d'une preuve permet de garantir que le fichier de preuve présenté n'a pas été falsifié et que les données qu'il contient ne sont pas corrompues. La vérification restitue les informations présentes dans la preuve, telles que: date et heure du dépôt, identification du destinataire de la lettre recommandée, etc. "

Note that, from https://www.pernaud.fr/info/glossaire/12937097/recommande-avec-accuse-de-reception-preuve-du-contenu ([mirror](https://archive.vn/LUqKx)):

> "'il appartient au destinataire d'un envoi recommandé qui en conteste le contenu, d'établir l'absence des documents annoncés" [Cass civ 2-me 6 novembre 2014 n°13-23568](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/juri/id/JURITEXT000029743294/)

Also, note the difference between the role of a notaire and a huissier: https://www.juridique-assistance.fr/un-notaire-et-un-huissier-de-justice-deux-metiers-a-ne-pas-confondre/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/6JxXs)).

Comment: preuve de contenu à la mode !